# How will Makoto and Chiaki be together in the future?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-girl-who-leapt-through-time

In The Girl Who Leapt Through Time, Chiaki and Makoto talk at the end of the movie and he uses his last jump to return to the future. He confesses his love for Makoto and tells her to find him in the future, hinting they will be together then.

Why not stay behind together? If he goes back to the future, she will age, and when they meet once more, she will be an old woman (I'm assuming the apocalyptic future where he comes from is many decades from the present). Is he expecting her to have no family, and have loved no one, until they meet again?

Comment: Makoto vows to ensure the painting's existence so Chiaki can see it in his era. I think him saying he'll wait for her in the future can mean that he will see the painting and through that metaphorically meet Makoto. I think she'll be long dead in his era. don't think this is a physical meeing he's talking about.

Answer (score 1):

Chiaki never really planned to stay back. He always had the intention to return to his time. All he wanted to do was to experience the past time. Makoto happened to be there and he happened to fall in love with her. But they are separated by many eras. I'm sure Chiaki has many loved ones - friends and family back in his time. He seems like a reasonably outgoing normal dude.

I guess it comes down to a toss up between Makoto and everyone else from his era.

Staying back would mean bidding an abrupt good bye to everyone in the future who's going to be worried sick because of his disappearance.

Returning to the future gives him the opportunity to express his feelings for Makoto and say his good byes. When he returns, Matoko would be long "dead", but he hopes to reunite with her through the painting that will now be "alive" because of her.